# create associative array from collection in laravel for checking purposes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative

I am having an hard time trying to create an associative array from a collection in Laravel. The array should then be used for case checking.

I get my collection like this:

```
$collected_items = $user->collected_items()->where('model_id', '=', $model_id)->get();
```

I need to extract only some relevant data from this collection like `'color_id'`

I need to check the `color_id` because I should run different code if the `color_id = 0, 1 or 2`

Since I don't want to do a DB query for every case I thought I'd better eager load the data and then put it in an associative array;

However for the life of me I can't create this array
I tried:

```
$array_of_colors = []

    foreach ($collected_items as $i) {

                    if ($i['color_id'] == 0) {

                        $array_of_colors += ['black' => $i->model_color_id];
                    }
                    if ($i['color_id'] == 1) {

                        $array_of_colors += ['colored' => $i->model_color_id];
                    }
                    if ($i['color_id'] == 2) {

                        $array_of_colors += ['white' => $i->model_color_id];
                    }


                }
```

Then I would use the `$array_of_colors` to check if I have a case of black then do something, is white something else etc etc.

Comment: You actually get a collection back have you looked into using the `filter` option?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter

Comment: You are right, thanks, I used the filter() option and then max() and min() on the filtered collection to assign the values I needed to some variables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it that way I highly recommend using the Collection functions available in Laravel. In particular I think `filter()` will work well for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter

Something like this:

```
$black_items = $collected_items->filter(function ($value, $key) {
  return $value->model_color_id == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_of_colors = []

foreach ($collected_items as $i) {

                if ($i['color_id'] == 0) {

                    $array_of_colors[] = ['black' => $i->model_color_id];
                }
                if ($i['color_id'] == 1) {

                    $array_of_colors[] = ['colored' => $i->model_color_id];
                }
                if ($i['color_id'] == 2) {

                    $array_of_colors[] = ['white' => $i->model_color_id];
                }


            }
```